# Each Group by expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference, need a work around

Tags: sql-server, sql-view

Hi this code runs perfectly as a query but when i try to parse it as a view i have the error on the title of this post. "Each Group by expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference". I need a second pair of eyes to help me work around this problem. 
Thank you!

```
SELECT Codigo, Nome, DataNascimento, IDADE, DataAdmissao, FUNCAO, CodEstabelecimento, Vencimento
, 'GRATIFICACOES' AS Expr1, 'SUB.TURNO' AS Expr2, OUTROS, DataUltProcessamento, 'DESCONTO MULTAS' AS Expr3
, AntiguidadeMeses, 'FALTAS' AS Expr4, Ano
FROM (
    SELECT F.Codigo, F.Nome, F.DataNascimento, (
            SELECT FLOOR((CAST(GETDATE() AS INTEGER) - CAST(F.DataNascimento AS INTEGER)) / 365.25) AS Expr1
            ) AS IDADE, F.DataAdmissao, (
            SELECT Descricao
            FROM dbo.Categorias
            WHERE (Categoria = F.Categoria)
            ) AS FUNCAO, F.Categoria, F.CodEstabelecimento, F.Vencimento, (
            SELECT SUM(Valor) AS G
            FROM dbo.FuncRem
            WHERE (
                    Remuneracao IN (
                        'R21'
                        ,'R23'
                        ,'R24'
                        ,'R25'
                        ,'R94'
                        ,'R96'
                        )
                    )
                AND (Funcionario = F.Codigo)
            ) AS 'GRATIFICACOES', (
            SELECT SUM(Valor) AS ST
            FROM dbo.FuncRem AS FuncRem_2
            WHERE (
                    Remuneracao IN (
                        'R05'
                        ,'R22'
                        ,'R43'
                        ,'R50'
                        )
                    )
                AND (Funcionario = F.Codigo)
            ) AS 'SUB.TURNO', (
            SELECT SUM(Valor) AS O
            FROM dbo.FuncRem AS FuncRem_1
            WHERE (
                    Remuneracao NOT IN (
                        'R21'
                        ,'R23'
                        ,'R24'
                        ,'R25'
                        ,'R94'
                        ,'R96'
                        ,'R05'
                        ,'R22'
                        ,'R43'
                        ,'R50'
                        )
                    )
                AND (Funcionario = F.Codigo)
            ) AS OUTROS, (
            SELECT SUM(Valor) AS A
            FROM dbo.MovimentosFuncionarios
            WHERE (CodMov = 'D15')
                AND (Funcionario = F.Codigo)
            ) AS 'DESCONTO MULTAS', F.DataUltProcessamento, DATEDIFF(m, F.DataAdmissao, GETDATE()) 
            AS AntiguidadeMeses, (
            SELECT SUM(Tempo) AS F
            FROM dbo.CadastroFaltas
            WHERE (
                    Falta IN (
                        'F12'
                        ,'F10'
                        )
                    )
                AND (Funcionario = F.Codigo)
                AND (YEAR(Data) = M.Ano)
            ) AS 'FALTAS', M.Ano
    FROM dbo.Funcionarios AS F
    INNER JOIN dbo.Situacoes AS S ON F.Situacao = S.Situacao
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.FuncRem AS FR ON FR.Funcionario = F.Codigo
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.MovimentosFuncionarios AS M ON F.Codigo = M.Funcionario
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.CadastroFaltas AS CF ON CF.Funcionario = F.Codigo
    WHERE (S.Tipo = 0)
        AND (
            F.CodDepartamento IN (
                912
                ,914
                ,916
                ,921
                ,922
                ,924
                ,931
                ,934
                ,937
                )
            )
        AND (M.Ano = 2016)
    GROUP BY F.Codigo, F.Nome, F.DataNascimento, F.DataAdmissao, F.Categoria, F.CodEstabelecimento
    , F.Vencimento, F.DataUltProcessamento, F.Situacao, CF.Falta, M.Ano, CF.Tempo, FR.Remuneracao
    , FR.Valor, M.CodMov, M.Valor
    ) AS R
GROUP BY Codigo, Nome, DataNascimento, IDADE, DataAdmissao, FUNCAO, CodEstabelecimento, Vencimento
, AntiguidadeMeses, DataUltProcessamento, 'GRATIFICACOES', 'FALTAS', 'SUB.TURNO', OUTROS, 'DESCONTO MULTAS', Ano
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453517/each-group-by-expression-must-contain-at-least-one-column-that-is-not-an-outer-r)

Comment: yes it works, but now i have another problem... in the columns Gratificacoes SUB. TURNO , DESCONTO MULTAS and FALTAS i dont have the sum value instead i have text with the column names in each line... how to pass this?

Comment: `'SUB.TURNO' AS Expr2` returns a string literal aliased as `Expr2`.  If you want to output the column TURNO from one of your subqueries the syntax is `[SubQueryName].[FieldName] AS [AliasName]`.  In this case I think it might be `[R].[SUB.TURNO] AS [Expr2]` but I'm 100% convinced I've correctly read your SQL statement (there is a lot going on!).

Comment: Solved it! Thanks for the tips!