# Microsoft SQL Server: Error with Group By

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm new to Microsoft SQL Server 2014. I run this SQL code:

```
SELECT TOP(10) 'DBSG' as seek_entity, * 
FROM DBSG..PM00200
```

and get this result:

[image]

Next, I want to find out total line items for that entity with code below.

```
WITH vw_pm00200_all AS
(
    SELECT TOP(10) 
        'DBSG' as seek_entity, *    
    FROM 
        DBSG..PM00200
)
SELECT
    seek_entity,
    COUNT(*) AS total
FROM
    vw_pm00200_all
GROUP BY
    1
```

Sadly, I get this error. I have no idea why it failed.

> Msg 164, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
> Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

Lastly, please advise is Microsoft SQL Server based on [Transact-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-reference?view=sql-server-ver16)?

Comment: Yes - the query language for SQL Server is **Transact-SQL** (or in brief: **T-SQL**)

Comment: TQ @marc_s for the info and correcting my code. any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running into this problem here: [Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453517/each-group-by-expression-must-contain-at-least-one-column-that-is-not-an-outer-r)

As the answer points out, grouping by a constant literal is pointless as it is the same for all results.  Count(*) will return the same result as Count(*) with a GROUP BY.

If this is just test code and you plan on using a CASE statement (with different values) in place of the string literal, you may have better luck.

Yes, T-SQL is Microsoft SQL Server's flavor of SQL.

Comment: hi @user8338883, please explain more about 'constant literal'.

Comment: Your 4th line, "'DBSG' as seek_entity" is adding a column called seek_entity which has the value 'DBSG' for all values, https://www.geeksengine.com/database/basic-select/literal-character-strings.php

Comment: As I am not a T-SQL expert, I cannot explain why you cannot group by this, but is not providing any value in the GROUP BY since it is consistently the same, i.e., a GROUP BY on a non-changing value is the same as removing it entirely.  If you want to add back in the 'seek_entity' column, you could add it back in later: 
`SELECT COUNT(*) AS total, 'DBSG' AS seek_entity FROM vw_pm00200_all`